# How to fix "Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] at Route" in node js?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I got `Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]` error.

on `route.js` I have following code:

```
const product_controller = require('../controllers/product.controller');
router.get('/test', product_controller.test);
```

On `product.controller` I have following code:

```
module.exports = {test: function(req,res){res.send('Greetings from the Test controller!');},}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my machine XD.

```
const express= require('express');
var router= new express();
var path= require('path');

const product_controller = require('../controllers/product.controller');
router.get('/test', product_controller.test);

router.listen(3000, (err) => console.log("listening on port 3000"));
```

Maybe you should check your paths and also log out the `product_controller.test` to see if it shows up undefined or a function.

I recommend using `.use()` to route requests to a particular file. This way you can keep all logic related to a particular route in a single file.

```
var product_controller = require('./controllers/product.controller');
app.use('/test', product_controller);
```

Here is the entire app.

Server.js

```
const express= require('express');
var app= new express();
var path= require('path');

var product_controller = require('./controllers/product.controller');
app.use('/test', product_controller);

app.listen(3000, (err) => console.log("listening on port 3000"));
```

product.controller.js

```
const express= require('express');
var router= new express();
var path= require('path');

router.get('/', function(req, res)
 {
    res.send('Greetings from the Test controller!');
 });

module.exports= router;
```

The file structure is as follows
MAIN APP FOLDER >

- Node modules
- controller > product.controller.js
- server.js
- package.json